# PyTorch: Sizes of tensors must match on 2 input neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am attempting to recreate a 2 input neural network from this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/moving-from-keras-to-pytorch-f0d4fff4ce79

I have copied the network described in the post and adjusted it so that it fits my data. The first input is from GloVe Word embeddings while the other is numerical features about the text data.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,hidden_size,lin_size, embedding_matrix=embedding_weights):
        super(Alex_NeuralNet_Meta, self).__init__()

        # Initialize some parameters for your model
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        drp = 0.1

        # Layer 1: Embeddings.
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(size_of_vocabulary, pretrained_embedding_dim)
        self.embedding.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(embedding_matrix, dtype=torch.float32))
        self.embedding.weight.requires_grad = False

        # Layer 2: Dropout1D(0.1)
        self.embedding_dropout = nn.Dropout2d(0.1)

        # Layer 3: Bidirectional CuDNNLSTM
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(pretrained_embedding_dim, hidden_size, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)

        # Layer 4: Bidirectional CuDNNGRU
        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size*2, hidden_size, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)

        # Layer 7: A dense layer
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size*6 + X2_train.shape[1], lin_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

        # Layer 8: A dropout layer 
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drp)

        # Layer 9: Output dense layer with one output for our Binary Classification problem.
        self.out = nn.Linear(lin_size, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        
        '''
        here x[0] represents the first element of the input that is going to be passed. 
        We are going to pass a tuple where first one contains the sequences(x[0])
        and the second one is a additional feature vector(x[1])
        '''
        h_embedding = self.embedding(x[0].long())
        h_embedding = torch.squeeze(self.embedding_dropout(torch.unsqueeze(h_embedding, 0)))
        #print("emb", h_embedding.size())
        h_lstm, _ = self.lstm(h_embedding)
#         print("lst",h_lstm.size())
        h_gru, hh_gru = self.gru(h_lstm)
        hh_gru = hh_gru.view(-1, 2*self.hidden_size )
        print("gru", h_gru.size())
        print("h_gru", hh_gru.size())

        # Layer 5: is defined dynamically as an operation on tensors.
        avg_pool = torch.mean(h_gru, 1)
        max_pool, _ = torch.max(h_gru, 1)
        print("avg_pool", avg_pool.size())
        print("max_pool", max_pool.size())

        # the extra features you want to give to the model
        f = torch.tensor(x[1], dtype=torch.float).cuda()
        print("f", f.size())

        # Layer 6: A concatenation of the last state, maximum pool, average pool and 
        # additional features
        conc = torch.cat(( hh_gru, avg_pool, max_pool, f), 1)
        #print("conc", conc.size())

        # passing conc through linear and relu ops
        conc = self.relu(self.linear(conc))
        conc = self.dropout(conc)
        out = self.out(conc)
        # return the final output
        return out
```

And during runtime I get an error on the concatenation line:

```
RuntimeError: Sizes of tensors must match except in dimension 0. Got 33164 and 20 (The offending index is 0)
```

From the dimensions of the outputs, I can see where the problem lies but I am not sure how I can fix it

The data inputs to the network is:

```
torch.Size([20, 150])
torch.Size([33164, 40])
```

The sizes of each layer output is:

```
gru torch.Size([20, 150, 80])
h_gru torch.Size([20, 80])
avg_pool torch.Size([20, 80])
max_pool torch.Size([20, 80])
f torch.Size([33164, 40])
```

For the example above the batch size is 20, hidden_size is 40, the number of rows in numerical data features is 33164 and its feature size is 40.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: What do the two inputs correspond to?

Comment: How can you expect your inputs to be concatenated when the dimensions do not align at all? How does the 33164 correspond to your sequence length/feature depth/batch size?